# C++ Concurrent Queue pushing by reference or value

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have the following code which consists of me pushing some data to a concurrent queue object from the PPL (Concurrent Runtime) library in C++. The data gets updated constantly (for every frame of a video) and is done as below:

```
short* data;
data = new short[num_samples];
// data gets updated continuously
conQueue->push(data);
```

I am initializing the queue as shown below:

```
conQueue = new concurrency::concurrent_queue<short*>;
```

with the following libraries:

```
#include <ppl.h>
#include <concurrent_queue.h>
```

My question is - would the data that gets pushed to the queue be copied over by reference or value? I keep seeing mixed comments online. The reason is I am pulling each of the data out of the queue from another thread and I want to make sure that the data is what is accurate for that exact frame it was from (and not from some current frame if being stored by reference).

I can't seem to think of ways I can test this out to see. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Your queue stores pointers and you pushing pointer to it. It'll be copied by value. But it's quite unsafe unless you transfer ownership to consumer thread and don't store data pointer in producer thread.

Comment: If I'm pushing a pointer to it, doesn't it store by reference then though? Pointers store the address instead of the actual value right?

Comment: It stores a value of a pointer.

Comment: The terminology of 'by reference' and 'by value' here is confusing. In this situation your pointer is being copied - so no, the data being pointed to is not copied. C++ has a special for references though, so many people would not refer to this as being 'by reference'. You would need to be careful to never access the data on the enqueuing thread again, and remember to clean up the data on the thread that pops the pointer out of the queue.

Comment: @ChrisPearce Oh so you're saying it's essentially being stored by reference? But, I'm popping the data from the queue somewhere else and using it. I'm not sure what you mean by the second part

Answer (score 0):

By using `new`, you have created an array exists on the heap. A pointer is returned to you, which is essentially just the address in memory of the array you created. Making a copy of this address by passing it into the queue will not create a new copy of the array.

Because you are passing a pointer to this heap-allocated data around, you will need to be careful about when you `delete` (when calling `new` you should always `delete` once you're finished with the data). You wouldn't want to `delete` the array straight after putting that pointer into the queue, or you might cause your program to crash when you try to pop the pointer out of the queue and use it.

To avoid this sort of problem, make sure that it's the code that pops the data out of the queue that `delete`s the array once it's done.

I highly recommend avoiding this any many more headaches by using the smart pointer types in the C++ standard library such as [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of handling raw pointers directly.